Does duality mapping preserve cross ratio?
I'm new to projective geometry.
I learned the definition of cross ratio of 4 collinear points and that of 4 concurrent lines in $\mathit{P}\mathbb{R}^{2}$.
The question is, by duality we can map 4 collinear points into 4 concurrent lines. Does such maps always keep the cross ratio of the points and that of their images (cross ratio of the lines) the same?
By duality mapping, I mean a map $f$, satisfying:

if $P$ is a point, then $f(P)$ is a line.
if $l$ is a line, then $f(l)$ is a point.
$P$ lies on $l$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $f(l)$  lies on $f(P)$.

And the question can be described as:
Is it always the case $(AB;CD)=(f(A)f(B);f(C)f(D))$, no matter how we choose the mapping $f$, where $(AB;CD)$ is the cross ratio $\frac{AC}{BC}:\frac{AD}{BD}$.
I think it's true if we construct the mapping in regard of homogeneous coordinates.
If $A,B,C,D$ are 4 collinear points, we can pick their homogeneous coordinates to be
$\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}= \vec{a}+\vec{b},\vec{d}= k\vec{a}+\vec{b}$
then $(AB;CD) = k$
Let $f(\vec{a})=\vec{a}$, that is, the dual of the point $A = \vec{a}=(P,Q,R)$ is the line $Px+Qy+Rz = 0$. So the dual of the point has the same coordinate of its preimage. It's just a matter of whether we interpret the coordinate as a point or a line.
If so, we have $(f(A)f(B);f(C)f(D))=k$, too.
However, as far as I know there are more than one way to construct duality mappings (pole and polar, etc.). And so comes the question.
Thank you for any response!

Perhaps you can show how you can get with this using homogeneous coordinates

@Deane hi, I've edited the question so it is more explicit.

If you have two "dualities" $f$ and $f'$, then $f'\circ f^{-1}$ is a self-equivalence of the projective plane (it sends points to points and preserves alignment). This means that this is a projective transformation (this is not a completely trivial statement!), which are known to preserve the cross-ratio.
Try to see that this means that is one duality preserves the cross-ratio, then they all do.

Thank you. For any duality mapping $f^{\prime}$, if both $f$ and $f'\circ f^{-1}$ preserves cross ratio, we have $f' = (f'\circ f^{-1})\circ f$ so it also preserves cross ratio :-)

does this mean that if I have four points on a circle, and I take their tangents to that circle, these four lines preserve the cross ratio?
